# Get a opencv_gpu function working in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have an OpenSUSE 13.2 System with Qt5 and OpenCV installed with cudasupport. The Hardware is an Intel i5 processor with an integrated intel gpu chip and a NVidia GForce 940 M and i have tried to compile this file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try
    {
        cv::Mat dst_mat;
        cv::Mat src_host = cv::imread("/home/peter/testCuda/testCuda/GothaOrangerie.JPG", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
        cv::namedWindow("Result",cv::WINDOW_NORMAL);
        cv::imshow("Result", src_host);
        cv::waitKey();
        cv::gpu::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);
        clock_t t = clock();
        cv::gpu::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        t = clock() -t;
        cv::Mat result_host(dst);

        cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();

        t = clock();
        cv::threshold(src_host, dst_mat, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        t = clock() -t;
        cout << ((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
        cv::imshow("Result", dst_mat);
        cv::waitKey();
    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation in the shell with

```
g++ main.cpp -o threshold `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv` -lopencv_gpu -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64
```

works pretty well i can run the small program without any issues. If i try it with the Qt5 IDE it returns me this error.

```
OpenCV Error: No GPU support (The library is compiled without CUDA     support) in mallocPitch, file /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/dynamicuda/include/opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp, line 126
Error: /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/opencv-2.4.9/modules/dynamicuda/include/opencv2/dynamicuda/dynamicuda.hpp:126: error: (-216) The library is compiled without CUDA support in function mallocPitch
```

If i run the shellcompiled program with this command

```
optirun ./threshold
```

i get the same error.

The .pro File is

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-10-15T04:02:07
#
#-------------------------------------------------



TARGET = testCuda

LIBS += -L/usr/lib64/
LIBS += -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -lopencv_gpu
LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs`

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

and the Qt compilation command is

```
22:58:12: Running steps for project testCuda...
22:58:12: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
22:58:12: Starting: "/usr/bin/make"
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../testCuda -I/usr/include/QtCore -I/usr/include/QtGui -I/usr/include -I. -I../testCuda -I. -o main.o ../testCuda/main.cpp
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o testCuda main.o    -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/ -L/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64 -lopencv_gpu `pkg-config opencv --cflags --libs` -lQtGui -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtCore -lpthread
22:58:13: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited normally.
22:58:13: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Anybody an idea how to fix that?

Comment: so you can compile both using QtCreator and in shell, the error you get is a runtime error?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sry for not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Deinstalling the preinstalled libopencv-2.4.9 package solved it.